# Sql Error Message ID 3013 & 4305 for Standby / Read-Only database that we use for import data heavily

Tags: sql-server-agent, standby, logging

Sorry. I am not a DBA, but a SQL Developer, so I am trying to get some general support/feedback on my case (and when I Googled the issue, remedy seems so scattered so I decided to post here).

I got this error message on SQL Server Agent for one of "Standby / Read-Only" databases.

[image]

**SQL Server Error 3013 and 4305**.

Bottom is some of error messages:

```
6_Exec SQL Nightly_StandByReporting_Run0235AM_PST,Error,1,
BNSQL2\PCCDAILY,6_Exec SQL Nightly_StandByReporting_Run0235AM_PST,Exec,,Executed as user: 
BNSQL2\JDoh. ...0000001<c/>
 which is too recent to apply to the database. 
An earlier log backup that includes LSN 201999000000891200001 can be restored. 
[SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 4305)  RESTORE LOG is terminating abnormally. 
[SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 3013)  The log in this backup set begins at LSN 
203741000000458400001<c/> 
which is too recent to apply to the database. An earlier log backup that includes LSN 
201999000000891200001 can be restored. 
[SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 4305)  RESTORE LOG is terminating abnormally. 
[SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 3013)  The log in this backup set begins at LSN 
203744000000476800001<c/> 
which is too recent to apply to the database. An earlier log backup that includes LSN 
201999000000891200001 can be restored. 
[SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 4305)  RESTORE LOG is terminating abnormally. 
[SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 3013)  The log in this backup set begins at LSN 
203749000000381600001<c/> which is too recent to apply to the database. 
An earlier log backup that includes LSN 201999000000891200001 can be restored. 
[SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 4305) RESTORE LOG is terminating abnormally. 
[SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 3013) The log in this backup set begins at LSN 
203788000000038400001<c/> which is too recent to apply to the database.
```

When I Googled, this is brief reason.
"BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally"

I am not sure why this happened, but I can only guess that this happened due to some type of memory or hardware issues because we use this database **heavily to import data** (into other database).

When I searched more for remedies, following are given ([from this site](https://www.stellarinfo.com/blog/sql-error-3013-backup-database-terminating-abnormally/)):

- Check Security Permission for user
- Delete the Previous Backup
- Perform Full Backup Restoration

I am not sure how to apply for **"Standby / Read-Only" database though**.

I would appreciate for any help to fix the issue.

Comment: The logs are complaining that you are trying to restore your standby database with backed up logs which have already been applied. If you want to restore it any further then you’ll need some newer backups from the primary. This job shouldn’t be managed by a developer so I recommend you speak to your friendly neighbourhood DBA

Comment: @AndrewSayer Thank you for your feedback. What does it mean by "backed up logs which have already been applied"?  Does it mean like somebody tried to do something on the database (beside Read/Select operation)?  Can I modify/fix this Stand-by database any longer? I could do the whole new replication from new backup files though.

Comment: I was saying that the thing that is producing that error log is erroring because it is trying to do work that has already been done. Having reread them, I realize that actually it's complaining that you've skipped some transactions with your apply job. You will need to locate the lost transaction log backup (easy enough if you have access to the source DB - talk to your DBA), or start again with another database backup and this time make sure you don't miss a transaction log backup (again, talk to your DBA).

Comment: @AndrewSayer Thanks. What does it mean by "some transaction with your apply job"? I am not sure on "apply job" part.

Comment: The job which is writing this error log, it is trying to restore transactions to your standby database